# How to post some inbound message to salesforce with username and password?

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, webservices

I want to post some inbound request to salesforce by using salesforce credentials.
Can anyone suggest me the best and secure way to make this communication happen between external system and salesforce.

Comment: What Salesforce API are you using? What type is your remote system? (ETL platform, Java app, Ruby app, PHP app, Heroku Connect, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

A good guide to the different Salesforce APIs is:

- [Which API Should I Use?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm)

If you are looking to just post some information to Salesforce, and just want to use the user's username and password stored on another system, I'd recommend using the REST API and use the Username Password Flow (warning this is not the safest approach since you are storing and then passing username and passwords):

- [OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en_US)

First, go create a Connected App by going to Setup -> Create -> Apps -> Connected Apps -> New and fill out the new app form and enable oauth.

If you decide to use the Username/Password Flow, you'll need to get an access token first. To do this, you can use a method like the one below, which takes the username, password, and a client ID and client secret - both available from the Connected App settings for the connected app you just created - and retrieves the access token(session ID). The method below is in Apex and is an example, you will need to develop and run this type of method in your own system.

```
public static String requestAccessToken(String user, String pass, String client, String secret) {
        String username = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(user, 'UTF-8');
        String password = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(pass, 'UTF-8');
        String clientId = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(client, 'UTF-8');
        String clientSecret = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(secret, 'UTF-8');

        //Build the HTTP Request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(
            'grant_type=password' +
            '&username=' + username +
            '&password=' + password +
            '&client_id=' + clientId +
            '&client_secret=' + clientSecret
        );

        //Send HTTP Request
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);

        Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(resp.getBody());

       //Return the Access Token
        return (String) m.get('access_token');
    }
```

Once you have the access token, you are able to make a calls against the Salesforce REST API - all by just having the username and password stored - until the token expires and you need to use the refresh token flow.

If you are looking for the most secure way of having data posted from an external system to Salesforce, I would suggest you look into the [OAut2.0 Web Server Authentication Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US) and use the [OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&language=en_US) to handle expired tokens... but that requires a bit more than just some simple http requests to Salesforce.